# Foursquare API return different data than it's website why?

Tags: json, api, foursquare

We are using Foursquare API for one of our mobile app and to show nearby data we are using below API to get nearby Food locations.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=33.17450984381138,-96.78465677816064&radius=10000&llAcc=10000&categoryId=,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&oauth_token=HRL4YZXETY4RKRB1DV5XPPLQVVZUZEQYODTWKSICEFMU1RRN&v=20180705

Here *4d4b7105d754a06374d81259* is category id for Food.

But the data return by the API is different from the data showed on their website and this becomes an issue for us.

Below are screenshots of data shown on their website and shown on our mobile app, it's a big difference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why there is a downvote, it will be great to let all know why?

Comment: What does that category id do?  What language does the API use?  Sorry, but we won't be able to help you if you don't give us enough information to do so.  Please edit your question to include code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Tau Why code is required as I have given API, which returns complete response. which is again different from their website. language or platform can be any, that is why I have shared the API.

Comment: You must contact with the foursquare cus care or find the difference in provided docs ..

Comment: @vaibhav They have ref. StackOverflow on their website. https://developer.foursquare.com/docs see the support link.

Comment: You only mentioned that you "are using Foursqure API" to do something.  How are we supposed to know what your app does if we don't even know how it works?  Did you create a function to handle the id yourself?  We need more information than just `I used this API to create my app.  Why doesn't it work?`

Comment: @Tau It's working, I am not saying it does not work but the thing is data is different. I have shared the API as I know I am building the API in wrong way or have missed something in API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are looking for wrong API, if I change the path to `v2/venues/search?` to `v2/search/recommendations?` with the same `ll=33.17450984381138,-96.78465677816064` and `categoryId=,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259` it shows me the same result as they have on their website.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/search/recommendations?locale=en&explicit-lang=false&v=20181219&categoryId=,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&limit=30&mode=locationInput&near=Frisco%2C+TX&nearGeoId=72057594042620495&ll=33.17450984381138,-96.78465677816064&oauth_token=HRL4YZXETY4RKRB1DV5XPPLQVVZUZEQYODTWKSICEFMU1RRN&v=20180705

[image]